# How to get the geometry value from coordinates

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapserver

I have a table with empty geometry column. I have two columns in the same table which has xcoordinate and ycoordinate values. I want to get the geometry value formed by these two coordinates. The geometry is POINT so I am using st_geomfromtext('POINT(x y)') function.

I tried below syntax to update the geometry column the_geom in table 't1':

```
 update t1 set the_geom=st_geomfromtext('POINT('||t1.xcoordinate||t1.ycoordinate||' )');
```

However this gives an error that :

```
"POINT(3458196941 )" <-- parse error at position 17 within geometry
```

I am not using '||' string concatenation correctly here. Can any one correct me ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, It should be like this:

```
update t1 set the_geom=st_geomfromtext('POINT('||t1.xcoordinate||' '||t1.ycoordinate||' )');
```

It worked fine!!

Comment: You can try ST_Make point too, more elegant than string concatenation, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than formatting text for [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), you should directly use the numeric coordinate data since it is [faster and lossless](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58630/1872):

```
update t1 set the_geom = ST_MakePoint(t1.xcoordinate, t1.ycoordinate);
```

And if you also need to assign an SRID:

```
update t1 set the_geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(t1.xcoordinate, t1.ycoordinate), 4326);
```