# Inserting a PostGIS point using Npgsql

Tags: postgis, c#

I'm trying to insert points using C# into a PostGIS / PostgreSQL database. I'm using the Npgsql driver. I suspect this is less a driver issue and more a syntax issue due to me being unfamiliar with ST_GEOMETRY.

Here's the code:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;Database=XXX;");

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO points(name, point) VALUES(2, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:longitude :latitude)', 4326));", conn);

var longitude = command.CreateParameter();
longitude.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
longitude.DbType = DbType.Double;
longitude.ParameterName = "longitude";
longitude.Value = fix.Longitude;
command.Parameters.Add(longitude);

var latitude = command.CreateParameter();
latitude.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
latitude.DbType = DbType.Double;
latitude.ParameterName = "latitude";
latitude.Value = fix.Latitude;
command.Parameters.Add(latitude);

conn.Open();

var dr = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

When I run the code, I get a Npgsql.NpgsqlException with an error message `ERROR: XX000: parse error - invalid geometry`" The Hint property has a message `"POINT(:l" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry`.

How do I construct a proper SQL statement to insert ST_GEOMETRY using parameters?

Comment: This has less to do with ST_GEOMETRY and more to do with improper embedded SQL syntax. Far better to build the string in a variable and send that than hard-code an invalid string that won't be seen as two variables.

Comment: I thin there is a nicer way to do this -- at least now, see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ST_GeomFromText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) is used to read [Well-known text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), so you would need to format a string to pass as a parameter. However, [this is one of the slowest way to make a point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58630/1872), and is subject to parse errors of the WKT string (which is the error shown in your question).

Use [ST_MakePoint](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html), which can directly use numeric parameters.

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO points(name, point) VALUES "
    "(2, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude), 4326));",
    conn);
```

Answer (score 1):

[NpGSQL supports a direct mapping for Points to the PostGIS Geometry type](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html?q=PostgisGeometry) through the class [`PostgisGeometry`](http://www.npgsql.org/api/NpgsqlTypes.PostgisGeometry.html).

With that you should be able

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(
  "INSERT INTO points(name, point) VALUES (:name :point);",
   conn
);
command.Add( "name" );
command.Add( myPostgisGeometry );
```