# Slow upload time in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, performance

I have a csv file of 144 millions different points with latitude and longitude values. Using the following SQL statement, it currently takes me more than 24 hours to upload the data:

```
CREATE TABLE pts(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, geom geometry(POINTZ, 3005));
```

Do you know if there is a way you could upload all the data faster?

Comment: What tool are you using to import the data from CSV ?

Comment: Why are you using pointz, which is for 3d points, for lat long values?  Also, as Robin said, how are you uploading the points?  As discussed in this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58605/which-function-for-creating-a-point-in-postgis, there are large performance differences between approaches.

Comment: Maybe you should first read the CSV data into PostgreSQL with COPY and build the PostGIS geometries then based on the imported table. Or perhaps you do that already.